# How to see which website an app is trying to access?

Tags: networking, ip, hosts, thunderbird, plasma

Hello Unix StackExchange,

I've recently started using [StevenBlack's /etc/hosts file](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts), and it seems to have broken some apps I've been using. So far I've noticed that Thunderbird can't log into GMail accounts using Oauth2 anymore, and the BBC Weather widget broke as well. It's very clear to me that these have been caused by the /etc/hosts change from the time the errors occurred at and the characteristic error messages stating that a certain server could not be accessed.

I've tried to look for (Google and BBC) related servers in the hosts file, however, commenting out some lines didn't fix things, unfortunately. It would be of much use to me if there was a way to know which server/website exactly an application is failing to connect to.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion: Close all web accessing programs... Run wireshark... access a "broken" site and see what the packets tell you.

Comment: What I do is redirect to a webserver on my network, I can check the access log for 404's and the referring URL.  When there is something I want to allow (like jquery) I'll mirror a copy to that webserver.  Which reminds me I need to go check about unblocking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It would be of much use to me if there was a way to know which server/website exactly an application is failing to connect to."
Unfortunately we can't guess, so you'll have to find out for yourself. What you'd want to do is see where the packets go. So, open up Wireshark or an alternative and attempt to access a website or application that doesn't function correctly. Then, look where those packets are going and comment out the incorrect entry.

To stop using that custom `/etc/hosts` file, you could temporarily replace it with a default version:

```
mv /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bak
echo "127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4" > /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Thank you! A packet analyzer was what I was looking for. For the record, I couldn't fix GMail so far — even though I commented out some of the domains it was seemingly trying to access, OAuth2 wouldn't work, and i couldn't tell the difference between the packets with or without OAuth2. As for the Weather widget, BBC integration seems to have broken on its own, unrelated to /etc/hosts.